# Where to set UITableview style to grouped style

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My Tabview controller has a tableview appearing as the first and initial view. The view controller class is a subclass of uitableviewcontroller, so I am not using XIB for this. 
Since I am giving the view name directly in the interface builder for the MainWindow of the tab view, I am not sure where I can set the style of the tableview, which appears in 'plain' style at the moment. I want to change it to 'grouped', however there is no code where I call and allocate the tableview controller (in which case I would have used the initWithStyle).

Any ideas on how I can change this initial tableview to grouped style instead of plain style?

I also tried overriding the initWithStyle and set it like below, but does not work.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try the following then:

```
UITableView* table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:myFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Replace `UITableView` by the name of your custom class

Comment: Hi, The link points towards dynamically setting the style based on configuration values. I just want to statically assign the grouped tableview style to the current table view.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I am not using code to allocate the tableview anywhere. In my tab view controller, this table view is set as the first view. So, not sure where I should put the above code?

Comment: I found the solution by overriding initWithCoder instead of initWithStyle in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538038/change-uitableviewcontrollers-style-in-tab-bar-application

Answer (score 1):

you can choose the tableview from the .xib and set the style to Grouped